# Passing a value from a main form to a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have two tables, `tblContacts` and `tblAddresses` which are related by `contactID` as a foreign key on `tblAddresses`. Not every address is associated with a contact, as some of them are related to organizations but not people. Currently, the relationship between the tables is a one-to-many relationship between contacts and addresses, as sometimes a contact can have more than one address (office, mailing, etc.) I am not enforcing referential integrity on this relationship because of the above reason- not every address has a contact.

In my form `frmContacts`, which has `tblContacts` as record source, I have a subform `fsubAddresses`, which has `tblAddresses` as a record source, that needs to be linked to the `contactID` of the current record. However, the parent-child relationship between the form and the subform on `contactID` does not seem to be effective- when I set the control source to a text box in my subform to `contactID` I see a null value, rather than the expected `contactID` number matching the current contact.

I have created a somewhat patchy workaround and I'd like to see if there is a better solution or a different way for me to structure this relationship.

I created a text box `txtContactID` in the `frmContacts` main form with the control source set to `contactID` then created a locked combo box in the `fsubAddresses` subform with the default value set to `txtContactID` and this displays the correct `contactID` for the current record. I then set the control property of this combo box to `contactID` so it would pass that value into the `tblAddresses` field for `contactID`. This works, but I feel like I have over-complicated the problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Show your current code plz

Comment: What you do you have as the Link Master and Link Child Fields properties on the parent form's subform control?

Comment: @HansUp I have `ContactID` as the field for both master and child and have the result "Show `tblAddresses` for each record in `tblContacts` using `ContactID`"

Comment: What are the RecordSources of *frmContact* and *fSubAddresses*? Please Edit post with information (see link below question).

Comment: @ElizabethHam Sounds like you described what you see for the relationship properties.  I'm asking about properties of the subform control.

Comment: @ HansUp those are the properties of the subform control when I right-click on the subform from the form in design view.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to access the `contactID` of the main form and use it to fill the subform's `contactID` when adding a new address. Also, I think that you do not want to see the `contactID`, neither on the main form nor on the subform, and in fact you don't have to. Access uses the relationship defined by Link Child Fields and Link Master Fields to fill the `contactID` of the subform's recordsource when adding a new address in the subform. This will not happen before the address is saved, so you won't "see" that value on the subform while the record is still new and unsaved.